# Check whether text contains an image url (Regex)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, image, url

So, let's say someone is typing something into a textarea.

Something as simple as this:

```
<textarea id="posttext" style="height: 50px; width: 80%;"></textarea>
```

I've already gotten the textarea to detect changes in the text area, however, let's say someone copy and pastes an image from another site, like this: http://celticevolution.com/images/test-201.gif

How would I get that image url? Also, let's say they were multiple images, and, how would I get it to display multiple images.

This is similar to how Facebook's posting system works.

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: How would they paste an image into a textarea? Do you mean you want to detect image-urls in the textarea?

Comment: you already have the image url! its http://celticevolution.com/images/test-201.gif

Comment: Yes, but, what if there are multiple images? How would I grab them from that URL. Let's just say just www.facebook.com, and, I would want to grab all the images from Facebook.

Comment: @CCTheContradiction, grabbing all the images from Facebook is gonna take a while... ;)

Comment: I should probably scrap that and just do the basics first then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check to see if its an image url and react accordingly you can use a regular expression in your onchange event of the text area to see if it contains a gif, jpg, or png

```
var result = text.match(/http:\/\/\S+(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif)/g);
```

if you want to iterate through the pages images, you can capture the page in an ajax call, then do a different regex to match all the "results" (as matched above) and add them to an array, then iterate through them from the interface...like fb does.

Comment: if result is true, then you can add an image under your textarea like face book :)

Comment: Okay, great, now how would I get the match to then have a <img src" + piece of the string + "/> attached to it.

Comment: text.match(/<img [^>]*src=".*?[^\]"[^>]*/>/g);

Comment: then when you have an array of those..(you might get more than you bargained for with that one) you can pull the src with the initial matches regex from the array

Comment: Wait, I'm soo confused. when I try to put that regular expression into the javascript. I get an error. And, I would split it into an array and then?

Comment: once you have your array of strings matching image tags, you need to parse out the source url's form the image tags, or just use them I suppose..but be careful because you'll get ALL the images from the page...you might just want the images from the content, you'll have to figure out a way to differentiate the two